# localstorage.clear() not working

Tags: javascript, html

i am writing a post it notes using html5 localstorage.
But somehow the clear button is not working.
here is the code

```
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="note_text">
    <input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add Sticky Note to Self">
    <input type="button" id="clear_button" value="Clear The Notes">

</form>
<ul id="stickyList">

</ul>
```

The Js

```
    function init()
{


    var button = document.getElementById("add_button");
    button.onclick = createSticky;
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        if (key.substring(0, 6) == "sticky") {
            var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
            addStickyToDOM(value);
        }
    }
}


function addStickyToDOM(value) {
    var sticky = document.createElement("li");
    sticky.setAttribute("class", "sticky");
    var t = document.createTextNode(value);
    sticky.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("stickyList").appendChild(sticky);

}


function createSticky() {
    var value = document.getElementById("note_text").value;
    var key = "sticky_" + localStorage.length;
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    addStickyToDOM(value);
}


function clearStorage() {
    localStorage.clear();
    cleart('cleaded THe Stoegae');
}

var clearBtn=document.getElementById("clear_button");
clearBtn.onclick=clearStorage;


window.onload = init;
```

Here is the live fiddle
[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/bzpwjvt4/)

When i click on the clear button it does nothing.
Please tell me where am i doing it wrong.
thanks,

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: I can see no issues in the code other than this `cleart('cleaded THe Stoegae')` part.

Comment: @Marc, please tell us what the issue is : is the localStorage not cleared or the UI does not reflect the change?

Comment: @Marc I posted the answer just to see the error. Checking console is ctrl+shift+j in chrome. And in JsFiddle you refresh pressing Run again.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini, what you want here is some framework that has two-way databinding like Angular JS to see the change. Or in the `clearStorage` method remove the `li` tags from the DOM.